# Which function could look like this?

Tags: functions

[image]

It converges y=x when x goes to be large. This function is defined for x>=0.
It passes (0,0) and (1,1).

I couldn't imagine which function look like this...

Comment: Maybe $y = x+\frac x{x+1}-\frac {x^2} {x^2+1}$

Comment: In more generality one set of function you can try testing is $y = x + \frac {x^a}{x^a+1}-\frac{x^b}{x^b+1}$ and with $0<a<b$.